# TradingView Pine script - signals arriving late when calculated at higher resolution

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

When I calculate MACD using daily resolution, my signals come at the expected date. However when I calculate them on a finer resolution (such as 4 hours), they arrive precisely 24 hours later than on the daily chart. I would have expected them to come sooner on the finer resolution charts.

Can anyone explain why this is and how I can possibly fix it?

Here is a strategy that highlights the issue:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Resolution issue", 
 process_orders_on_close=true, 
 calc_on_every_tick=true
 )

src = close
fastLength = 12
slowLength = 26
signalLength = 9

// --------------------- Daily  

dailyFastMA = ema(src, fastLength)
dailySlowMA = ema(src, slowLength)

dailyMacd = dailyFastMA - dailySlowMA
dailySignal = sma(dailyMacd, signalLength)
dailyHist = dailyMacd - dailySignal

dailyOutMacD = security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', dailyMacd, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dailyOutSignal = security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', dailySignal,  gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dailyOutHist = security(syminfo.tickerid, '1D', dailyHist,  gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// --------------------- 4 hourly  

fourHourlyFastMA = ema(src, fastLength * 6)
fourHourlySlowMA = ema(src, slowLength * 6)

fourHourlyMacd = fourHourlyFastMA - fourHourlySlowMA
fourHourlySignal = sma(fourHourlyMacd, signalLength * 6)
fourHourlyHist = fourHourlyMacd - fourHourlySignal

fourHourlyOutMacD = security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', fourHourlyMacd, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
fourHourlyOutSignal = security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', fourHourlySignal,  gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
fourHourlyOutHist = security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', fourHourlyHist,  gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// --------------------- Plot

plot(dailyOutMacD ? dailyOutMacD : na, title="Daily MACD", color=#77FF00, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(fourHourlyOutMacD ? fourHourlyOutMacD : na, title="4hr MACD", color=#0077FF, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)

plot(dailyOutSignal ? dailyOutSignal : na, title="Daily Signal Line", color=#77FF00, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(fourHourlyOutSignal ? fourHourlyOutSignal : na, title="4hr Signal Line", color=#0077FF, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

The blue line is the high resolution 4hr data and green is the daily data. See an [image of the graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv1gk.png). The blue line (4hr) lags behind the green line (daily) by 24 hours, I would have expected the blue to be ahead of the daily as the daily should only be correct once a day where as the 4hr show be correct 6 times per day.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
source = close
res = "240"
fastMA = ema(source, 12*6)
slowMA = ema(source, 26*6)

macd = fastMA - slowMA
signal = sma(macd, 9*6)
hist = macd - signal

outMacD = security(tickerid, res, macd, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
outSignal = security(tickerid, res, signal, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
outHist = security(tickerid, res, hist, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it didn't improve the result. I have updated the above question and included a full script (using lookahead_on) and also a screenshot showing the output.